# Spring boot Content-Disposition filename in Russian

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

the problem with downloading a file from the server, the file name may contain Russian text, when downloading it substitutes ??????? instead of Russian letters, and the download breaks, a file without an extension named 1 is downloaded. How do I fix it?

```
@GetMapping("/download/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable Long id) {
    File file = fileStorageService.getFile(id);
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"")
            .contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/docx"))
            .body(file.getData());
}
```

Question number two, is there a dynamic way to specify the content-type depending on the file extension?

Answer (score 1):

```
ContentDisposition contentDisposition = ContentDisposition.builder("attachment")
                .filename(file.getName(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                .build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition.toString())
                .contentType(MediaType.valueOf(file.getType()))
                .body(file.getData());
```